# What is the relationship between C# 10 and .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a link between .NET versions and do they pack the language versions in them? Googling is not delivering any clear answers. Looks like everyone except me knows this stuff.

Any reading links will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) table.

Note that this only minimum supported language version. Many language features work fine in older, non-supported .NET versions, but require the csproj file to be edited manually to add `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` to specify that you want to use the latest supported c# version.

So my approach is basically:

1. Use the newest .NET version you can
2. If you cannot use the latest .Net version, add the `LangVersion` switch to get the latest c# version. This is not technically supported, so might cause issues, but I have yet to encounter any significant problems.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: I thought .NET Core 3.1 was still supported through Dec 2022 ....

Comment: I stand corrected.https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-december-13-2022/

Answer (score 2):

You can lookup the details at Microsoft, for a pure language perspective look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history

The compatibility is listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#c-language-version-reference):

> C# 11 is supported only on .NET 7 and newer versions. C# 10 is
> supported only on .NET 6 and newer versions. C# 9 is supported only on
> .NET 5 and newer versions. C# 8.0 is supported only on .NET Core 3.x
> and newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

The C# language is implemented both in Roslyn (the compiler) and in the runtime.

That said, most of the features don't need the runtime and work just by having the newest SDK and specifing the language version in the  tag in the csproj file.

I wrote a blog post about it here:
https://blog.genezini.com/p/how-to-use-c-sharp-11-features-in-dotnet-6-or-older-versions/